# How to put width 100% on facebook comment

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-comments

How to put width 100% properly on the code below? Please help I'm a beginner on HTML and CSS

```
<div>
<fb:comments expr:href='data:post.url' expr:title='data:post.title' expr:xid='data:post.id' mobile='yes' numposts='2'/>
</div>
```

Comment: What did you actually try, and what were the results ?

Comment: I tried putting this on my blogger post but the width is too long . I want to fit it on my blogger page by putting width="100%" but i don't know how I only know the very basics of html

Answer (score 0):

Use this, facebook's own utility to generate comment box code. You do have an option to modify the width there.

You can specify width in pixel if you want, or you can specify width as `100%` for fluid width.

`data-width="100%"`

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments

Comment: If I generate my comment from there, I have to do it on every post. Just putting width 100% on the code given above will make my life easier because I just have to put it once.